# How to Generate IPv6 Mask from IPv6 Prefix in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ipv6

Implement a function to convert IPv6 Prefix ( 0 to 128 ) to the corresponding mask *(ffff:ffff style)* in javascript / typescript.

Examples:

```
33 => 'ffff:ffff:8000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000'

128 => 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff'

118 => 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fc00'
```

Comment: Why do you use such notation for an IPv6 prefix length? Yes, IPv6 addresses are masked, but, unlike IPv4, we do not represent or use an explicit mask separate from the prefix length. Even with IPv4, we are moving away from representing and explicit mask, although there is so much that does that it will never go away. IPv6, from the start, eliminated using an explicit mask notation.

Comment: this is the product ask. I'm just implementing it. I have explained this to them but they still wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

The following program converts the given prefix to IPv6 Mask.

I was using http://ip-address.js.org/#address6 for other IP Validations, but it doesn't have this mask conversion function.

```js
const HEX = 16;
const BINARY = 2;
const MAX_PREFIX = 128;
const MIN_PREFIX = 0;
   /**
   *
   * @param prefix
   * @returns ipv6 netmask address
   *
   * Fill an array with 1s for given number of prefix bits
   * Fill the remaining bits with 0s
   * chunk it with 16 elements and covert each chunk to hex
   *
   */
  static getNetmaskForPrefix(prefix: number): string {

    const prefixArr: number[] = new Array(prefix).fill(1);
    const chunkArr = Array.from({
      length: Math.ceil(prefixArr.length / HEX),
    }, (_v, i) => prefixArr.slice(i * HEX, i * HEX + HEX));

    // Converting from binary to hex
    let subnet = chunkArr.map((item) => {
      return parseInt(item.join('').padEnd(HEX, '0'), BINARY).toString(HEX);
    }).join(':');

    if (subnet.length < 35) {
      subnet = `${subnet}::`;
    }

    return subnet;
  }
```